# Typescript object is possibly undefined

Tags: typescript

```
interface c {
    state?: {b: string}
}

const x: c = { state: {b: 'c'}}
console.log(x.state.b)
```

In the above code, In interface c, state is an optional property.

However when I want to access the property b of the state object whenever it is set, it is giving me this error, Object is possibly 'undefined'. What is the right way to fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's because `state` can be undefined, and the compiler doesn't always know when it is definitely defined.

You can tell it you're sure it's defined, just use:`x.state!.b`

Answer (score 4):

If you are sure that an optional(field marked with `?`) has a value, this can be achieved by checking it for a value:

```
if(x.state !== undefined){
  console.log(x.state.b)
}
```

you can use a `!` to mark it as present:

```
console.log(x.state!.b)
```

Comment: wow! what is the different between x.state?.b  and  x.state!.b    ? 
I didn't know this syntax:   x.state!.b    ;  I was going to use   x.state?.b    (the same but with interrogation mark...)  that is working in some place but no work in some other...  
I'm pretty confused

Comment: `object?.property` becomes undefined when object is undefined, `object!.property` marks the value as "i am sure the value will be there" and will throw a runtime error if object is undefined